# Converting Shapefile to Geojson

Tags: python, mapping, geospatial, geojson, shapefile

In short, I am trying to convert a shapefile to geojson using gdal. Here is the idea:

```
from osgeo import gdal

def shapefile2geojson(infile, outfile):

    options = gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(format="GeoJSON", dstSRS="EPSG:4326")
    gdal.VectorTranslate(outfile, infile, options=options)
```

Okay then here is my input & output locations:

```
infile = r"C:\Users\clay\Desktop\Geojson Converter\arizona.shp"
outfile = r"C:\Users\clay\Desktop\Geojson Converter\arizona.geojson"
```

Then I call the function:

```
shapefile2geojson(infile, outfile)
```

It never saves where I can find it, if it is working at all. It would be nice if it would pull from a file and put the newly converted geojson in the same folder. I do am not receiving any errors. I am using windows and Jupyter Notebook and am a noob. I don't know if I am using this right:

r"C:\Users\clay\Desktop\Geojson Converter\arizona.shp"

Comment: I tested your code and it worked for me so I don't think there is anything wrong with the code. Maybe something is wrong with the .shp file?